# MySQL full text searching data included in foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, myisam, full-text-indexing

First of all my data is stored using the MyISAM engine as I'm aware InnoDB does not support full text search indexing at this time on linux. I do however use foreign keys, although obviously this is not referentially enforced.

I have 3 tables comprising of manufacturers (man_id, name), models (model_id, man_id, name) and products (man_id, model_id, summary, description).

What I would like to do is a full text search on the products table, but include the manufacturer name and model name as well as summary and description. Essentially searching 4 fields.

I release full text searching won't work in this way as only columns in the table can be indexed and not foreign key values. Does anyone have any ideas on how one might achieve something to this effect?

Comment: InnoDB supports fulltext indexes as of v5.6.4: http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/12/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-4/   so you could ditch MyISAM workarounds and go full-blown InnoDB now if you want.

Comment: @MarcB Yes that is true, unfortunately this version has only been released as a development version for Microsoft based servers. The latest version for Linux based servers (which I'm using) is v5.5 which still doesn't have this functionality.

Say this was an InnoDB database with full text search support, how would you go about including references to foreign keys in a query when doing a full text search?

Answer (score 2):

You could join these tables and run searches against the join, as the following example shows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stuff` text FULLTEXT KEY,



) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stuff` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `index_table_b_on_text` (`stuff`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


SELECT table_a.*
FROM table_b JOIN table_a ON table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE MATCH(table_b.stuff) AGAINST ("hamster")
      AND MATCH(table_a.stuff) AGAINST ("leopard");
+----+---------------------------------------------+
| id | stuff                                       |
+----+---------------------------------------------+
|  3 | A brown leopard jumped over a lazy hamster. |
+----+---------------------------------------------+
```